# Sublime Text 2 split active screen like dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver, sublimetext2, live-preview

At work, I have to jump into old mysql_query procedural website build higgledy-piggledy (some var are camelCased AND underscored, no indent code, page are build in table ...)

Anyway, usually I m using ST2, but here I can't. So to search my line code, I use dreamweaver to click on the screen preview and the cursor drop on the code line I want.
I do not like and I don't know dreamweaver. But as code is UNREADABLE, that is the only way I have to work.(My boss doesn't want rebuild theses sites).

Here is my question, does anybody know for ST2 a way (or a plugin) to split screen and click on screen preview to go right to the code line just like dreamweaver preview does ?

Regards.

Comment: I know of no such plugin, and it might be hard to e.g. embed a browser engine (such as WebKit) inside a ST:2 frame.

Comment: Thx for your answer, what would you do in my place ? Continuing with dreamweaver or would you try another editor ? At my office I m under mac, I used to dev under windows.

Comment: Please don't do it. Check this [Jeffrey Way's Sublime Text 2 video course](https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/) and let Windows/Dreamweaver go forever (I used to code there).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple, you will never find something like that.

Try here - http://webdesign.about.com/od/windowshtmleditors/tp/windows-wysiwyg-editors.htm

WYSWIG html editors.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sublime CodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel), as well says [this page](http://www.henriquebarroso.com/my-top-10sublime-2-plugins/):

> *...This plugin brings a little of IDE functionality into ST2. This plugin reads all your code and is able to code-complete, jump into
>   definitions and function call tooltips. Although sometimes looks a
>   little buggy, it’s still worth having it around. It’s a huge time
>   saver, especially when you are dealing with other’s people code.*

If is suitable for that project you can remove the package later.